# Chrome: pass JavaScript variable through window.open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have two html files (Certificate1.html and Certificate2.html) that both reference the same JavaScript file.  Certificate1.html calls one JavaScript function, which takes information from the html file, opens a new window, and assigns the information to the second window like this:

```
function passName() {
    var FirstN = document.frmUserName.inFirstN.value;
    var LastN = document.frmUserName.inLastN.value;
    var CourseN = $('.sCourse').text();
    var CourseHrs = $('.sNumHrs').text();
    var CourseNum = $('.sNum').text();

    var Cert = window.open("Certificate2.html");
    Cert.FirstN = FirstN;
    Cert.LastN = LastN;
    Cert.CourseN = CourseN;
    Cert.CourseHrs = CourseHrs;
    Cert.CourseNum = CourseNum;

}
```

Certificate2.html then calls another function, which sets that information in the correct locations:

```
function placeName() {
    document.getElementById("sUserName").innerHTML = FirstN + " " + LastN;
    document.getElementById("pCourseName").innerHTML = CourseN;
    document.getElementById("sHrs").innerHTML = CourseHrs;
    document.getElementById("sNum").innerHTML = CourseNum;
}
```

Right now this all works perfectly in Firefox and IE9, but not in Chrome.  When I run it in Chrome, I don't get any obvious errors, but when I check F12 there's an error saying that FirstN is undefined.

Does Chrome handle JavaScript variables differently than the other browsers?  What's going on?

Thanks,
Kristin

Comment: It's not the JavaScript variables that are different, it's the treatment of the `window` object -- and in particular whether properties you add to the window via your `Cert` reference (which is to the "external" window object) show up on the `window` object in the popup (which is the "internal" window object). It may also be down to differences in when the Same Origin Policy comes into effect (e.g., you're accessing the window *immediately* after opening it, when the document hasn't been loaded yet; Chrome may need you to wait for the `load` event first, but that's speculation).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the main window try to push those values onto the popup, I would recommend having the popup pull them from the main window, because A) I know that works, and B) I'm not certain of the timing issues around assigning to properties on `Cert` *immediately* after calling `window.open`.

So in "minimal changes" mode, I'd change `passName` like this:

```
function passName() {
    var FirstN = document.frmUserName.inFirstN.value;
    var LastN = document.frmUserName.inLastN.value;
    var CourseN = $('.sCourse').text();
    var CourseHrs = $('.sNumHrs').text();
    var CourseNum = $('.sNum').text();

    window.CertValues = {
        FirstN:    FirstN,
        LastN:     LastN,
        CourseN:   CourseN,
        CourseHrs: CourseHrs,
        CourseNum: CourseNum
    };
    window.open("Certificate2.html");
}
```

Or even:

```
function passName() {
    window.CertValues = {
        FirstN:    document.frmUserName.inFirstN.value,
        LastN:     document.frmUserName.inLastN.value,
        CourseN:   $('.sCourse').text(),
        CourseHrs: $('.sNumHrs').text(),
        CourseNum: $('.sNum').text()
    };
    window.open("Certificate2.html");
}
```

And then `placeName` like this:

```
function placeName() {
    var CertValues = window.opener.CertValues;
    document.getElementById("sUserName").innerHTML = CertValues.FirstN + " " + CertValues.LastN;
    document.getElementById("pCourseName").innerHTML = CertValues.CourseN;
    document.getElementById("sHrs").innerHTML = CertValues.CourseHrs;
    document.getElementById("sNum").innerHTML = CertValues.CourseNum;
}
```

*(In the above, I've used your convention for variable/property naming, but be aware that the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is to use camelCase with a lower-case initial letter for variables, reserving CamelCase with a capital initial letter for constructor functions [in line with JavaScript's `Date`, `RegExp`, etc.)*

Comment: T.J., Hmmm.  When I do it that way, it stops working in Firefox and IE (and still doesn't work in Chrome).  My guess is maybe because the first html form is cleared once the submit button is clicked?  I'm not sure how to keep it from doing that.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about naming convention!  I'll be sure to follow that from now on.